# Displaying Image with standalone python library

Tags: python

This has to be possible, as modules like opencv2 are written in python themselves.

So I have a picture '1.png', I know png has the following header in hexadecimal:

```
b\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x03\xe8\x00\x00\x02X\x08\x06\x00\x00\x00\xf1\x1e\xcc%\x00\x00\x00\x01sRGB\x00\xae\xce\x1c\xe9\x00
```

So, how can I display the picture if I have the data because of the command

```
open("filename",'rb').read()
```

The solution can work in either 2.7 or 3.x

Comment: Sorry, managed to submit my edit without explanation... if your question is not version-specific, then there's no need for the version-specific tags. Just the generic `python` tag is sufficient.

Comment: Are you sure the bytes object is correct, it is a valid image?

Comment: @jlandercy even if the bytes object isn't correct, I do not know which command I should run to display the image

Comment: @NavanChauhan while trying to help you I got an error about that bytes string, would you mind post a correct one in order to get a answer. Also read about [mcve] it helps to write good question.